# Python Socket help (Syntax error)

Tags: python

```
import socket

HOST = "swemach.se"
PORT = 21
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT)
data = s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print "%s" % data
```

Gives me error

```
File "main.txt", line 7
data = s.recv(1024)
  ^
SyntaxError: invaild syntax
```

What im going wrong? any tip/solution?

Answer (score 4):

You've forgot parenthesis.

```
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(( HOST, PORT)
```

^ there you go